# Operations between shape layer and csv layer

Tags: shapefile, csv

I have a .shp layer containing point geometry with xy coordinates in the attributes (left) and a .csv layer containing a square Origin/Destination matrix(right):
[image: Point and O/D matrix]

I need to perform this operation:

[image: operation]

where:

x_i and y_i are the x coordinates of the origins

x_j and y_j are the x coordinates of the destinations

p_ij is the value in the O/D matrix.

Any idea on how to do this?

Comment: It's probably easier calculating those equations in a spreadsheet programme like Microsoft Excel than in QGIS as there is no **SUM** function in the field calculator. You may be able to do this in other GIS software but I am not sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed, the whole calculation is better done in excel, thanks for the attention anyway!

Comment: No problem buddy, hope you get the results you want!